# GANEXUS: Cómo usar una colección en API

Tags: mysql, json, genexus, postman, webapi

Estoy practicando crear y consumir API REST en GX17 U9, y me solicitan que mendianre PostMan haga una sola consulta (usando el método POST) a la API con varios parámetros almacenados en la tabla (en este caso varios Números de Documento en una sola consulta), y que mediante PostMan me devuelva un solo resultado (es decir un solo JSON) con todos los datos bajo esos DNI (edad, tel, email, etc). Mi consulta sería, cómo podría hacer o como empezar esa api tanto en Procedure y con API? Se me hace difícil entender la documentación , desde ya, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [Cómo hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y otras secciones que aparecen en la misma página. Después vienes, editas tu pregunta y seguro que la comunidad estará más interesada en ayudar, ¿vale? Al menos, pon un código de tu intento (como mínimo de la llamada a la API) e intentaremos resolver los problemas/dudas concretos que surjan, y no esta pregunta tan general y sin detalles

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejo armarte un SDT para la respuesta y que tenga una subestructura del tipo collection.

Algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creas un procedimiento que será el webservice y que cargará y retornará el SDT de respuesta que creaste.

Aquí puedes revisar la documentación para crear servicios rest en GeneXus:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?28213,Toc%3ARest+web+services+in+GeneXus